# Ошибка при запуске Debian linux: /dev/sda2 contains a file system with errors, chek forced

Tags: linux, debian, boot

При запуске Debian GNU/Linux пишет ошибку "/dev/sda2 contains a file system with errors, chek forced." Это произошло после удара жёсткого диска.
Я понимаю, что нужно запустить некий fsck, но не понимаю как, ибо не могу что-либо напечатать

Прошу, помогите чем сможете. Спасибо

[image: В самом низу просит запустить fsck вручную, но не получается что-либо напечатать.]

Comment: Попробуйте использовать liveUSB и там уже проверять диск разными утилитами.

Comment: [дубликаты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=run+fsck+manually)

Comment: Если вы ударили жёсткий диск, то никакой fsck уже не поможет, это гарантированная смерть

Comment: После удара винта - надо с него срочно бэкапить важные данные на другой винт\облако, а после прогонять `mhdd`.